# Adblock Chrome update frequency- it's letting some ads through

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I use Adblock Plus [edit: originally wrote "pro"] for chrome, and occasionally I've noted that some ads will get through. Every time this has happened, updating the filters manually has fixed the problem, and they're almost always 3 or more days out of date. Is there a way to force updates more frequently than every 5 days? Or is there some other solution that would allow me to never see ads?

There is no place to modify this in the addon settings. If it matters, I'm using [easylist](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) and [easyprivacy](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easyprivacy.txt).

[edit Dec 20 2013] I switched from adblock plus for chrome to the regular adblock, and the same thing happens. Every few days, the filters will get so out of date that ads will slip through. There is no place for me to tune the filter settings that I know of. Is there anything I can do to keep these filters up to date enough that I won't see ads?

Comment: I suggest you try what Me Bender said. Try installing Adblock in Chrome, it is blocking better content than Adblock Plus in Chrome

Comment: I switched and it has the same problem, it's the list, not the addon.

Answer (score 4):

The update frequency is determined by your filter subscription.

From [adblock filter updates not very automatic](http://support.getadblock.com/discussions/questions/47-adblock-filter-updates-not-very-automatic) :

> The length of time we update filter lists by is decided by the list
>   itself, If you look at EasyList, for example, ([link](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt)), you will
>   see on line 6 that it expires every 4 days. AdBlock reads this and
>   understands that it only needs to update every 4 days. This is so that
>   EasyList's server doesn't get overloaded.

The above-linked EasyList list starts with these lines :

> [Adblock Plus 2.0]
>  ! Checksum: EtxsLx21pEe0QkBxTJFxHg
>  !
>   Version: 201312211410
>  ! Title: EasyList
>  ! Last modified: 21
>   Dec 2013 14:10 UTC
>  ! **Expires: 4 days (update frequency)**

If you are subscribed to EasyList ([site](https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/)), this means that the filter will update
every 4th day only. The reason for that is simply to conserve bandwidth on their web server.

Comment: Good information! Is there a way to manually update it more frequently? I'm doing it myself every couple of days when the ads start showing through anyways.

Comment: Not as far as I know. You could use a product such as [iMacros for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en) to automate the update. If you are using Windows, iMacros [can be scheduled](http://wiki.imacros.net/Browser_Automation#Schedule_Tasks) (but I never used it).

Answer (score 2):

Try https://getadblock.com/, instead. I know AdBlock Plus gets paid to let certain ads though, and AdBlock Pro might be guilty of the same thing. I use AdBlock (the one on that website is also free in the Chrome Store), and it has never let me down.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to new ads coming in, you may be able to use wildcards in some filters.

e.g. http://someadsite.com/39fg8ej3d8j347/something

You can block everything from this domain with:

http://someadsite.com/*

Firefox is more comprehensive about adding filters and I have had limited issues with ads coming through utilizing wildcards.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally miswrote the addon name. I use adblock plus.