# How to configure Chrome AdBlock to update every day?

Tags: google-chrome, adblock

I need to update AdBlock lists every day. Is there a way to configure this to be done automatically instead of going to the AdBlock Options page and pressing "update now" by hand every time?

Comment: You can't. The updates are determined by the time it takes for the list you're subscribed to, to update itself. [More info here](http://superuser.com/a/691547/167187)

Comment: What do you mean, @Vinayak? I know the lists I am subscribed to change every day while it takes many days for them to update automatically on my side.

Comment: Which lists are you subscribed to?

Comment: A lot of them, @Vinayak (I am a polyglot and use pages in a number of different languages actively). And I use to visit a nasty site (not porn though) pushing a lot of aggressive ads all over it. Every day they change their ads to evade AdBlock so that the ads become visible again, and every time I just go to AdBlock options, press "update now" and all the adds disappear again (after I wait for the update to finish and reload the page of course).

Comment: Could you be more specific about the lists you're subscribed to? AdBlock lists have an expiry date (update period) associated with them. For instance, EasyList is updated [every 4 days](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt)

Comment: "For instance, EasyList is updated every 4 days" - does this mean it does not change more frequently actually? I think it does not, so the question is how to override this expiry date. Another interesting question is how to view the URLs of non-custom subscriptions.

Comment: You can see the URLs for the list by hovering over the subscription's name in AdBlock settings. And yes, it means that EasyList is not updated each day, but every 4 days.